# LCD 16x2 Interfacing with STM32 (4Bit Mode)

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I am trying to interface LCD 16x2 with STM32 for learning purpose. I already interfaced with AVR, PIC etc. that code ported some of. But its not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
void LCD_init(void)
    {
    
      HAL_Delay(20);
      lcd_cmd(0x30);
      HAL_Delay(20);
      lcd_cmd(0x30);
      HAL_Delay(20);
      //Delay_Us(100);
      lcd_cmd(0x28);
      HAL_Delay(20);
       lcd_cmd(0x28);            // Function set (4-bit interface, 2 lines, 5*7Pixels)
       lcd_cmd(0x28);            // Function set (4-bit interface, 2 lines, 5*7Pixels)
       lcd_cmd(0x0c);            // Make cursorinvisible
       lcd_Clear();            // Clear screen
       lcd_cmd(0x6);            // Set entry Mode(auto increment of cursor)
    }
    
    oid lcd_cmd(__uint16_t cmd)
    {       GPIOB->ODR =0;
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            cmd = (cmd << 8) ;
            GPIOB->ODR =  (cmd & 0xf000);
            lcd_Strobe();
            cmd = (cmd << 4) ;
            GPIOB->ODR =  (cmd & 0xf000);
            lcd_Strobe();
            GPIOB->ODR =0;
    }
    
    
    void lcd_data(__uint16_t lcd_data)
    {     GPIOB->ODR =0x0000;
        // HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
         lcd_data = (lcd_data << 8) ;
         GPIOB->ODR =  (lcd_data& 0xf000)|0x400;
         lcd_Strobe();
         GPIOB->ODR =0;
         lcd_data = (lcd_data << 4) ;
         GPIOB->ODR =  (lcd_data & 0xf000)|0x400;
         lcd_Strobe();
         GPIOB->ODR =0;
    }
    
    
    void lcd_Clear(void)
    {
        lcd_cmd(0x01);
        HAL_Delay(5);
    }
    
    void lcd_String(const char *ptr)  // ptr pointing the address of displaying string
    {
        while (*ptr)             // check weather the endo of file then exit the loop
        {
            lcd_data(*ptr++);    // Sending data to LCD_data functions
        }
    }



 void lcd_Strobe(void)
{

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);// LCD Enable PIN to High
   // HAL_Delay(1);
    //Delay_Us(100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,EN_Pin, RESET);// LCD Enable High to Low
    //Delay_Us(100);PIO_PIN_11
   // HAL_Delay(1);
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Electrone - Hi, I see you are already getting help & have given more details about the specific problem & your troubleshooting so far, where you asked the same question on the [edaboard.com forum here](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/learning-stm32-lcd-interfacing-code-not-working.408540/). Other site members here might be able to help, but I don't want to waste your time (or mine) doing troubleshooting & asking for specific tests, which will overlap / duplicate the actions you are already doing, and the advice you are getting, on *that* thread. || Can you be more specific than "not working"?

Comment: sir ,i am struggling  it toclearout from 2 days , Its nothing display

Comment: posted here also to get more suggestion

Comment: Am testing in proteus simulator not in real hardware

Comment: Electrone  - As I said, I don't want to waste your time duplicating the help which is ongoing in that edaboard.com thread. However from a very quick scan of the code, you have only shown initialisation & helper functions (which may or may not be correct) and which should not actually compile (it says `oid` instead of `void` in one place). I don't see any code provided here which tries to display anything. Quickly checking on the edaboard.com forum I linked previously, I see you provided extra code (i.e. your `main.c`) there, but not here :( I recommend you make the question here *complete*.

Comment: You've left VEE floating and you have VDD & VSS to your LCD connected the wrong way around. If Proteus simulated smoke then you'd see it coming out of your LCD.

Comment: thanks @brhans ,I corrected it ,, any way not worked also in real hardware   . What about the code is there any wrong

Comment: Well then fix your diagram so that everyone else can see you've corrected it. Has correcting the power supply resolved the problem?

Comment: not resolved by the powersuply correction .

Comment: That is weird. Using the LCD should be identical on any MCU. It looks like the init code should not work anyway, and unused LCD data pins are grounded for unknown reason. Where is the strobe function, it might also have errors. Post the full code, as that can't work. Maybe you never initialized IO pins.

Comment: @justme Strobe code added

Comment: There's so many problems in the code. The MCU runs at multiple MHz. Do you think the LCD can see the EN pin go high and low? Also because the pin define is missing we can't be sure if you are toggling same pin high and low for EN.